# Search, match and copy directories into another based on names in a txt file

Tags: linux, bash, directory, copy

My goal is copy a bulk of specific directories whose names are in a txt file as follows:

```
$ cat names.txt
raw1
raw2
raw3
raw4
raw5
```

These directories have subdirectories, hence it is important to copy all the contents. When I list in my terminal it looks like this:

```
$ ls -l
raw3
raw7
raw1
raw8
raw5
raw6
raw2
raw4
```

To perform this task, I have tried the following:

```
cat names.txt | while read line; do grep -l '$line' | xargs -r0 cp -t <desired_destination>; done
```

But, I get this mistake

```
cp: cannot stat No such file or directory
```

I suppose it's because the names in the file list (`names.txt`) don't match in sorting with the ones in the terminal. Notice that they are unsorted and by using while read line doesn't work. Thank you for taking the time and commitment to help me.

Comment: It was a mistake when I was typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having problems following the logic of the current code so in the name of `K.I.S.S.` I propose:

```
tgtdir=/my/target/directory

while read -r srcdir
do
    [[ -d "${srcdir}" ]] && cp -rp "${srcdir}" "${tgtdir}"
done < <(tr -d '\r' < names.dat)
```

**NOTES:**

- the `< <(tr -d '\r' < names.dat)` is used to remove windows/dos line endings from `names.dat` (per comments from OP); if `names.dat` is updated to remove the `\r`' then the `tr -d` with be a no-op (ie, bit of overhead to spawn the subprocess but the script should still read `names.dat` correctly)
- assumes script is run from the directory where the source directories reside otherwise code can be modified to either `cd` to said directory or preface the `${srcdir}` references with said directory
- OP can add/modify the `cp` flags as needed, but I'm assuming at a minimum `-r` will be needed in order to recursively copy the directories

Comment: I tried to use your code, it doesn't return any error in stdout, yet when I check to see if the files were copied, there is nothing.

Comment: from your comments it looks like you've got windows/dos line endings (`\r`) in `names.dat`; I've update the answer to remove the `\r`'s

Comment: I think to be careful with that line generated by Windows. I'm highly grateful that it worked.

Comment: for future reference you can run `dos2unix <filename>` to remove the `\r`'s from `<filename>`; if you run `dos2unix names.dat` then you could go back to the previous version of my answer where the last line is just `done < names.dat`

Answer (score 1):

[UUoC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

```
cat names.txt | while read line; do ...; done
```

is better written

```
while read line; do ...; done < names.txt
```

`do grep -l '$LINE' |` is eating your input.

```
printf "%s\n" 1 2 3 |while read line; do echo "Read: [$line]"; grep . | cat; done
Read: [1]
2
3
```

In your case, it is likely finding no lines that match the literal string `$LINE` which you have embedded in single-qote marks, which do not allow it to be parsed for content. Use `"$line"` (avoid capitals), and wouldn't be helpful even if it did match:

```
$: printf "%s\n" 1 2 3 | grep -l .
(standard input)
```

You didn't tell it what to read from, so `-l` is pointless since it's reading the same stdin stream that the `read` is.

I think what you want is a little simpler -

```
xargs cp -Rt /your/desired/target/directory/ < names.txt
```

Assuming you wanted to leave the originals where they were.

Comment: I was using -l to make each line match the names in `names.txt`. I guess I'm getting a bit complicated, but when I use your last, simpler code, I get this error `cp: cannot stat 'raw1'$'\r': No such file or directory`

Comment: @DiegoMunoz - did you create `names.txt` on a windows machine?

Comment: It was created using excel and I exported it as txt on OSX

Comment: `sed -i 's/\r$//' names.txt` should fix it.